# Figure image showing upside down and distorted using \includegraphics, \textwidth also does not work

Tags: graphics

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and TexMaker and so far things were going well, but for some reason I'm having big troubles with adding figures.

My document is using:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

Compiling using TexMaker Quickbuild PDFLaTeX > Bib(la)tex > PDFLaTeX, I'm using graphicx to add figures like so:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.155]{figs/W297-ProcessingExample.jpg}
    \caption{Data processing procedure using Retiga E7 captures and GIMP, (Passivization layer damage example)}
    \label{fig:ProcSample}
\end{figure}
```

But for some reason, the first figure works fine (Added the exact same way as above), and the second is upside down, massive, and distorted as shown below:

[image: Figure Bug]

Using width=\textwidth instead of scale also gives me the bug "Dimensions too large", perhaps related?

FYI the image is nothing special, 1400x800 png... I tried using JPG and PDF, JPG does the same and PDF gives me "Dimensions too large" no matter what scale I set.

Anyone know what's going on here? I've tried several changes to no avail.

Comment: Welcome! Can you reproduce the problem with a different image? If not, there is probably something awry with the image. Did you convert png to jpg/pdf when trying those formats? Generally, it is better not to specify the extension when using `\includegraphics{}` and let the package figure things out for itself. (But specifying the extension wouldn't cause this kind of problem.) Can you provide code for a complete document we can use to reproduce the problem? If possible, use an image we all have. Otherwise, the problem likely is the image rather than anything on the LaTeX side.

Comment: If only one image misbehaves then typically something is wrong with that image and to debug that you should make a small and complete example and you must make the image available somewhere.

Comment: Hello cfr and Ulrike

You are both right, it was something wrong with the image, although I do not know what exactly is wrong with it.

It was produced using GIMP, and had several layers, but I exported it as a PNG. The solution I found in this case was first flattening the image, then exporting it.

This really shouldn't make a difference, but clearly something strange is happening with some of the data when exported with layers existing...

Thanks for getting me to look in the right spot for the problem!

Comment: If pictures are turned upside down, the reason is sometimes that there is some information in the meta data of the file which stores the orientation of the camera. This information is used by some software to rotate the image, but some software ignores this information. As for the size, there might be an issue with the resolution, i.e. a wrong DPI value.

Answer (score 0):

cfr and Ulrike were both right, it was something wrong with the image, although I do not know what exactly is wrong with it.

It was produced using GIMP, and had several layers, but I exported it as a PNG. The solution I found in this case was first flattening the image, then exporting it.

This really shouldn't make a difference, but clearly something strange is happening with some of the data when exported with layers existing...